# Get location path plus anchor link in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, location

I want to use the location path and anchor link (a link to an element in the page).
So i can use the value in my controller

So i have a path in my browser like so:

```
/atomics#icons
```

`/atomics` is the route and `#icons` is a link inside the page to an element
When i use `$location.path()` in my controller I only get `/atomics`,
i want to get `#icons` value aswell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an URL like `/atomics#icons` you can use the following `$location` functions to extract parts of it:

- [$location.path()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#path) will return `/atomics`
- [$location.hash()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#hash) will return `icons`

In case you want to extract querystring values you can also use `$location.search()`.

[Official $location documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location).

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to /atomics#icons from another location you have to give both below commands:

```
$location.hash('icons');
$location.path('/atomics');
```